# how to create dynamical button with respect to the webservice results

Tags: android, button

Am getting data from webservice in json format and want to display the results in dynamic buttons.i can able to display the results in a textview but i want to make it as to display dynamic button.my code is here

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 String url = "http://10.0.2.2:80/android_connect/home.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new LongOperation().execute(url);




}

private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    String data ="";
    TextView jsonParsed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsonParsed);
    int sizeData = 0; 

    protected void onPreExecute() {

         Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
         Dialog.show();

          }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
      BufferedReader reader=null;
              // Send data
            try
            {
                // Defined URL  where to send data
               URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

              // Send POST data request
              URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
              conn.setDoOutput(true);
              OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
              wr.write( data );
              wr.flush();
              // Get the server response
              reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              String line = null;
                   // Read Server Response
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                           // Append server response in string
                           sb.append(line + "");
                   }

                // Append Server Response To Content String
               Content = sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Error = ex.getMessage();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                           reader.close();
                }
                     catch(Exception ex) {}
            }

          return null;
  }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        Dialog.dismiss();
              if (Error != null) {
             jsonParsed.setText("Output : "+Error);

        } else {

         jsonParsed.setText( Content );

             String OutputData = "";
            JSONObject jsonResponse;

            try {

             jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);

             JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("menu");

             int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length(); 
               for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
              {
                  JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                  int pId = jsonChildNode.getInt("pid");


                     String Pid      = jsonChildNode.optString("pid".toString());
                      String Name     = jsonChildNode.optString("name").toString();

                   OutputData += "pid : "+ Pid +" "+ "content : "+ Name+" ";


               }


              jsonParsed.setText( OutputData );

             } catch (JSONException e) {

              e.printStackTrace();
           }


         }
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a crude answer but it will give you what you want.

You will have to add buttons to the view programmatically.

I don't know your Json result, so you will have to loop around that to add more buttons.

// Put a ViewGroup (i.e. `LinearLayout`) in your `activity_main.xml` with the `id` `btn_container`

in `postExecute`:

```
        LinearLayout buttonContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btn_container);
        Button button = new Button(buttonContainer.getContext());
        button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        button.setText("Json : " + OutputData);
        buttonContainer.addView(button);
```

Comment: I tried to show these button in to gridview but not getting, can u please tell  how to add gridview to these buttons...

Comment: GridView uses an adapter, you need a completely different approach